# How do I hide the field label for a HiddenInput widget in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I've got a bit of Django form code that looks like this:

```
class GalleryAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    auto_id=False
    order = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

And that makes the form field go away, but it leaves the label "Order" in the Django admin page. If I use:

```
order = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), label='')
```

I'm still left with the ":" between where the field and label used to be.

How do I hide the whole thing?!

Comment: See also the question [create a hidden field in django-admin](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4999005/509706) and [this django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11277)

Answer (score -22, accepted):

If you're using JQuery this should do the trick:

**Your form**

```
TO_HIDE_ATTRS = {'class': 'hidden'}
class GalleryAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    auto_id=False
    order = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=TO_HIDE_ATTRS))
```

**Javascript code to add to your template**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr:has(.hidden)').hide();
});
```

That works if you're rendering your form as a table. If you want to make it work with any kind of form rendering you can do as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('{{ form_field_container }}:has(.hidden)').hide();
});
```

And add `form_field_container` to your template context. An example:

If you render your form like this:

```
    <form>
        <span>{{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}</span>
    </form>
```

Your context must include:

```
'form_field_container': 'span'
```

You get the idea...

Comment: A more generic jQuery solution would be to do `$('.hidden').parent().hide()` since that will hide the whole div that contains the widget, the label, and any help text. It's a working solution for sure. I knew about adding custom attrs to the widget, but was trying to do the whole thing without resorting to JS. I'm just surprised Django didn't have a built-in way to do this.

Comment: Yes,`$('.hidden').parent().hide() also works, but relies in the fact that the parent of your field also contains the label. If you had something like `<tr><td>LABEL</td><td>FIELD</td></tr>` it wont work because parent would be the TD tag not the TR one.

I'm also surprised that there's no "django way" to do this.

Comment: Insane.. solution - Its like firing at flies !

Comment: Agree with @YugalJindle. There is nothing to do with jQuery if it can be solved in a cleaner way with template tags like {% if not field.is_hidden %}{{ field.label }}:{{ field }}{% else %}{{ field }}{% endif %}

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but I agree, this is solving this problem in the wrong place.

Answer (score 43):

Oraculum has got it right. You shouldn't be cleaning this up on the client side. If it is clutter, then you shouldn't be sending it to client at all. Building on Oraculum's answer, you should use a custom form template because you you probably still want the hidden values in the form.

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <div>
        {{ field.errors }}
        <span class="filter-label">{{ field.label_tag }}</span><br>
        {{ field }}
    </div>
 {% endfor %}

 {% for field in form.hidden_fields %}
     <div style="display:none;">{{ field }}</div>
 {% endfor %}
```

Using a custom form template to control hidden fields is cleaner because it doesn't send extraneous info to the client.

Answer (score 37):

I can't believe several people have suggested using jQuery for this...

Is it a case of: when the only tool you know is a hammer everything looks like a nail?

Come on, if you're going to do it from the client-side (instead of fixing the source of the problem in the back-end code) surely the right place to do it would be in CSS?

If you're in the admin site then it's a bit harder but if it's a regular page then it's easy to just omit the whole label from the form template, [for example](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template)

If you're in the admin site then you could still override the as_table, as_ul, as_p methods of BaseForm (see django/forms/forms.py) in your GalleryAdminForm class to omit the label of any field where the label is blank (or == ':' as the value may be at this stage of rendering)

(...looking at lines 160-170 of [forms.py](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/forms.py) it seems like Django 1.2 should properly omit the ':' if the label is blank so I guess you're on an older version?)

Comment: I guess you must be in the admin, the code pointed out by @Tonino above hard-codes a colon into the label when it's an admin form and bypasses the regular form mechanics. I guess I'd just use CSS in that case.

Comment: Looking at Django 1.4.5, this error still occurs in admin forms. [The template calls .label_tag](https://github.com/django/django/blob/67a937c2c24b7eee8be13a1d3faff595d8f45839/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html#L15) which [adds a colon unconditionally](https://github.com/django/django/blob/67a937c2c24b7eee8be13a1d3faff595d8f45839/django/contrib/admin/helpers.py#L126). I think the right server-side solution is to change the admin template.

Comment: hi @WilfredHughes :) it does look like this is fixed in Django trunk (you can give a `label_suffix` to the form constructor!)... problem still exists in 1.5.1 and changing the admin template to omit the `{{ field.label_tag }}` where desired seems to be the best way

Comment: Ah, so there is. That's an excellent workaround, but there's an [open ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11277) which sounds like it is the 'proper' solution.

Comment: I've added an answer that shows how to fix this. Yikes, this isn't an easy thing to fix.

Answer (score 20):

Try

{% for field in form.visible_fields %}

Comment: Have an upvote. I can't believe the JQuery kludges and CSS hacks are getting upvoted. This is a much nicer solution.

Comment: I would vote on it, but it leaves hidden fields away. More complete solution from @emispowder.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's simpler to achieve the ":" label omission for HiddenInput widget by modifying `class AdminField(object)` in `contrib/admin/helpers.py` from :

```
    if self.is_checkbox:
        classes.append(u'vCheckboxLabel')
        contents = force_unicode(escape(self.field.label))
    else:
        contents = force_unicode(escape(self.field.label)) + u':'
```

to :

```
    if self.is_checkbox:
        classes.append(u'vCheckboxLabel')
        contents = force_unicode(escape(self.field.label))
    else:            
        contents = force_unicode(escape(self.field.label))
        #MODIFIED 26/10/2009
        if self.field.label <> '':
           contents += u':'
        # END MODIFY
```

Comment: That's a good way to do it, though I'm not a fan of modifying anything in the django core. Could probably subclass the object and achieve the same effect that way though.

Answer (score 3):

Check the answer at [Create a hidden field in the admin site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999005/create-a-hidden-field-in-django-admin/6498907#6498907), it can be done without JavaScript by overriding `admin/includes/fieldset.html` From there, you can inject a CSS class, and do the rest.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, you should be able to pass `label_suffix` into the form constructor. However, the Django admin ignores this.

You've been bitten by two bugs in Django: [#18134 'BoundField.label_tag should include form.label_suffix'](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18134) (fixed in trunk, should be in 1.6) and to a lesser extent [#11277 Hidden fields in Inlines are displayed as empty rows](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11277).

Currently, the best solution is to override the admin fieldset template. Use a `HiddenInput` for your widget, then override the admin fieldset template ([documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#set-up-your-projects-admin-template-directories)). Just create a `templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html` with the following contents:

```
<fieldset class="module aligned {{ fieldset.classes }}">
    {% if fieldset.name %}<h2>{{ fieldset.name }}</h2>{% endif %}
    {% if fieldset.description %}
        <div class="description">{{ fieldset.description|safe }}</div>
    {% endif %}
    {% for line in fieldset %}
        <div class="form-row{% if line.fields|length_is:'1' and line.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% for field in line %}{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}">
            {% if line.fields|length_is:'1' %}{{ line.errors }}{% endif %}
            {% for field in line %}
                <div{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' %} class="field-box{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% if not field.is_readonly and field.errors %} errors{% endif %}"{% endif %}>
                    {% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
                    {% if field.is_checkbox %}
                        {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
                    {% else %}
                        {# only show the label for visible fields #}
                        {% if not field.field.is_hidden %}
                        {{ field.label_tag }}
                        {% endif %}

                        {% if field.is_readonly %}
                            <p>{{ field.contents }}</p>
                        {% else %}
                            {{ field.field }}
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if field.field.help_text %}
                        <p class="help">{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}</p>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2):

Based upon the solution by Wilfried Hughes I 've changed the fieldset.html with little improvements.

The code snippet below not only hides the input element instead if the fieldset contains only one single element which input-type is set to hidden it also hides the surrounding div-elements wasting no space in the form.

```
<fieldset class="module aligned {{ fieldset.classes }}">
{% if fieldset.name %}<h2>{{ fieldset.name }}</h2>{% endif %}
{% if fieldset.description %}
    <div class="description">{{ fieldset.description|safe }}</div>
{% endif %}
{% for line in fieldset %}
    <div class="form-row{% if line.fields|length_is:'1' and line.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% for field in line %}{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}"{% if line.fields|length_is:'1' %}{% for field in line %}{% if field.field.is_hidden %} style="display: none"{% endif %}{% endfor %}{% endif %}>
        {% if line.fields|length_is:'1' %}{{ line.errors }}{% endif %}
        {% for field in line %}
            <div{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' %} class="field-box{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% if not field.is_readonly and field.errors %} errors{% endif %}"{% endif %}{% if field.field.is_hidden %} style="display: none"{% endif %}>
                {% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
                {% if field.is_checkbox %}
                    {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
                {% else %}
                    {# only show the label for visible fields #}
                    {% if not field.field.is_hidden %}
                    {{ field.label_tag }}
                    {% endif %}

                    {% if field.is_readonly %}
                        <p>{{ field.contents }}</p>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ field.field }}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
                {% if field.field.help_text %}
                    <p class="help">{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}</p>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Just to add to this helpful post by lacki. I believe this template is for 1.6. @Lacki, can you verify?

Answer (score 0):

The following removes the ':' from all your form fields.  I've only tried it with the `forms.Form` class, but I believe it should work for `forms.ModelForm` too.

In Django forms, the ':' after the labels is the `label_suffix`.  You can change or remove the `label_suffix` by creating a subclass of `ModelForm`, here called `UnstyledForm`, and redefining the initialization function with `label_suffix` set to an empty string.  Then use your new `UnstyledForm` class.

```
class UnstyledForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('label_suffix', '')
        super(UnstyledForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class GalleryAdminForm(UnstyledForm):
    auto_id=False
    order = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, but i think it still better to iterate form.visible_fields & form.hidden_fields

```
<form action="{% url 'some_url' param %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        {% for field in form %}

            {% if not field.is_hidden %}
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    {{ field.label_tag }}
                    {{ field.error }}
                    {{ field }}
                </div>
            {% else %}
                {{ field }}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
     </div>
</form>
```