# Create Django Admin Intermediate page

Tags: python, django, admin

I need a way to have an intermediate page shown when I´ve saved a model in django admin.

What I want to accomplish is after "saving" a model, show a page with all the attributes of the model lined up and then have a button that says `Print`. I used to solve this with Jquery dialog div when clicking `save`. That meant that I showed the settings print view before actually saving the model but I need the model to validate first now.

Its like the way that the "delete model" action is implemented. I just can´t seem to find out where to start looking though.

**Edit:**
I´ve started looking in the `django.contrib.admin.options.py` for the `response_change` and `response_add` methods. Not sure how to override them though. And its only needed for one specific model so its not generic. Also I´ve discovered the list of templates in the Class ModelAdmin. Still not sure about how to proceed without hacking the admin to bits.

**Edit 2:**
Added my working solution down below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add views and urls to your ModelAdmin and overwrite your modeladmin add view to redirect accordingly.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = patterns('',
            (r'^my_view/$', self.my_view)
        )
        return my_urls + urls

    def my_view(self, request):
        # custom view which should return an HttpResponse
        pass
```

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, will get back after I try it out. Cheers!

Comment: Got it working now, thanks for putting me on the right track! Posting the code down below if anyone should be interested.

Answer (score 5):

You could create a form that had an extra step of validation for the 'are you sure' step.

Given this model in our models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Add a form in forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Person

class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    i_am_sure = forms.BooleanField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PersonForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.errors.get('i_am_sure'):
            # show the 'are you sure' checkbox when we want confirmation
            self.fields['i_am_sure'].widget = forms.CheckboxInput()

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(PersonForm, self).clean()

        if not self.errors:
            # only validate i_am_sure once all other validation has passed
            i_am_sure = cleaned_data.get('i_am_sure')
            if self.instance.id and not i_am_sure:
                self._errors['i_am_sure'] = self.error_class(["Are you sure you want to change this person?"])
                del cleaned_data['i_am_sure']

        return cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = Person
```

If you want to use this with Django admin. specify this form in your admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .forms import PersonForm
from .models import Person

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PersonForm

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

Note however that there's a bug with hidden inputs on Django admin forms. [There's a solution to that on this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18235005/509706).

Answer (score 0):

So, after a bit of coding I got it to work.

My modeladmin looks simular to this now

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = patterns('',
            (r'^my_view/$', self.my_view)
        )
        return my_urls + urls

    def my_view(self,request,pk):
        from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
        from django.template import RequestContext

        object = Model.objects.get(pk=pk)
        model_dict = model_object.__dict__
        return render_to_response('admin/app_name/model/model_view.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    @csrf_protect_m
    @transaction.commit_on_success
    def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        "The 'add' admin view for this model."
        model = self.model
        opts = model._meta

        if not self.has_add_permission(request):
            raise PermissionDenied

        ModelForm = self.get_form(request)
        formsets = []
        inline_instances = self.get_inline_instances(request)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
               new_object = self.save_form(request, form, change=False)
               form_validated = True
            else:
               form_validated = False
               new_object = self.model()
            prefixes = {}
            for FormSet, inline in zip(self.get_formsets(request), inline_instances):
               prefix = FormSet.get_default_prefix()
               prefixes[prefix] = prefixes.get(prefix, 0) + 1
               if prefixes[prefix] != 1 or not prefix:
                  prefix = "%s-%s" % (prefix, prefixes[prefix])
               formset = FormSet(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES,
                              instance=new_object,
                              save_as_new="_saveasnew" in request.POST,
                              prefix=prefix, queryset=inline.queryset(request))
               formsets.append(formset)
            if all_valid(formsets) and form_validated:
               self.save_model(request, new_object, form, False)
               self.save_related(request, form, formsets, False)
               self.log_addition(request, new_object)
               log.info('The new object has %s id' % new_object.id)
               return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/draws/contest/contest_view/%s' % new_object.id)  <-- changed to my new one
               .................
               .................
```

Created a html template in `templates/admin/app_name/model_view.html` and that is it!